# Fazer variavel esperar ser definida pelo usuario apos While? java

Tags: java, while, scanner

Olá, 
Quero que o usuário defina o valor de uma variável, mas a ele deve definir apenas após o **while**. Minha pergunta é como faz?
Aqui esta o pedaço que estou com duvidas.

```
public static void chama_programa(){

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int num;

   while (!(num < 1000)){
       System.out.println("Escreva um numero menor que 1000");
      num = sc.nextInt();
```

Pois do jeito que esta diz que a variável num precisa ser inicializada e se eu coloco um numero qualquer para ela passar pelo **while** direto sem dar chance de ser digitada.

Answer (score 0):

Não entendi direito sua pergunta. Mas vamos lá:
Inicie a váriavel com o valor 0, para previnir trechos em que ela não será utilizada.

```
    int num = 0;
       do {
         System.out.println("Escreva um numero menor que 1000");
         num = read.nextInt();
         if (num > 1000) {
           System.out.println("Erro! Numero invalido!");
         }
       }
       while (num > 1000);
    }
```

Nesse caso, o while irá testar o erro, se o número for maior do que 1000, ele irá repetir a mensagem, e após sair do while, irá manter o valor da variavel.
Espero ter ajudado

Comment: Isso na verdade não deu certo pois, pois como eu avia escrito, quando que eu inicio ela com um numero qualquer inclusive o zero o programa passa reto sem pedir para que o usuário digite.

Comment: Bom, então deve ter algum outro erro no seu código. posta o código completo por favor.

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que a intenção do seu código é forçar o usuário a digitar um número menor que 1000.

Ser for existem duas soluções:

A primeira solução é mais simples que é iniciar `num` com o valor 1000 e alterar a condição de iteração para uma condição que verifique se `num` é maior ou igual a 1000:

```
   int num = 1000;

   // como num é inteiro poderia ser (num > 999). 
   while (num >= 1000) { 
       System.out.println("Escreva um numero menor que 1000");
       num = sc.nextInt();
   }
```

A segunda solução é transformar o laço `while` em um laço `do-while` e alterar a condição de iteração para uma condição que verifique se `num` é maior ou igual a 1000:

```
do {
      System.out.println("Escreva um numero menor que 1000");
      num = sc.nextInt();
} while (num >= 1000) // como num é inteiro poderia ser (num > 999).
```